# EGL_BAD_CONFIG When Creating A PixelBuffer

Tags: c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, egl

I am having trouble creating a PixelBuffer in OpenGL ESv2.

If my config specifies `EGL_WINDOW_BIT` I can successfully call `eglCreateContext`.  However, when using `EGL_PBUFFER_BIT` I am getting an `EGL_BAD_CONFIG`.

I am working with an embedded system where I will be calling OpenGL ESv2 to do some GPGPU.  I do not have a windowing system to render to so I feel that I must use PixelBuffers.  My rendering calls render directly to a FBO with an attached Texture2D as the color buffer.

I am out of ideas on what's wrong with my configuration or how I can adjust it.  Any advice would be great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a function to print out all my possible configurations.  It turns out that even though glChooseConfiguration was returning GL_TRUE, it wasn't returning a configuration.

I wasn't getting any configurations.

OpenGL ES emulator apparently does not support PixelBuffers for OpenGL ES v2, only v1